# Como imprimir os números de dias de cada mes usando Array, String e byte?

Tags: java, array, string, byte

Estou tentando este código, mas ele não funciona.

```
public class MesDias {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Array String byte
        String Mes = {Jan, Fev, Mar, Abr, Mai, Jun, Jul, Ago, Set, Out, Nov, Dez};
        byte[] Dias = {31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

        for (int x=0; x<Mes.length(); ++x)
        for (int y=0; y<Dias.length; ++y)

        System.out.println(Mes[x] + " " + Dias[y]); 

    }
}
```

Comment: Realmente é necessário fazer desta forma? Por que não usar classes nativas que fazem isso?

Comment: Os meses estão em português ou em inglês? "Feb", "Apr", "May", "Aug" e "Dec" são em inglês, "Set" e "Out" são em português.

Comment: Pois é, os meses estão misturados. Vou corrigir. Obrigado, @Victor Stafusa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem alguns erros nesse código. O primeiro array não está declarado como array e os elementos não estão entre aspas.
Para mostrar cada mês respectivo com o dia, não necessita fazer um for aninhado.

Ex:

```
public class Datas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        // Array String byte
        String[] Months = { "Jan", "Fev", "Mar", "Abr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Set", "Out", "Nov", "Dez" };
        byte[] Days = { 31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

        for (int x = 0; x < Months.length; ++x)
                System.out.println(Months[x] + " " + Days[x]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Obrigado, @Júlio César Baltazar

Comment: Por nada, fico feliz em ajudar.

Answer (score 3):

Pode usar as classes do pacote [`java.time.*`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) para obter o número de dias de todos os meses do ano, por exemplo:

```
final int year = 2017;

for(Month month : Month.values()){

    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(year, month, 01);
    int numberOfDays = date.lengthOfMonth();
    String monthName = month.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, new Locale("pt", "BR"));

    System.out.println(monthName + " tem " + numberOfDays + " dias.");
}
```

---

#### [Funcionando no IDEONE](http://ideone.com/t2WPey)

Comment: Obrigado, @Renan Estou recém começando.